# Source of a Poincaré quote from a Busemann paper

Tags: mathematics, mathematicians, reference-request, quote

In his paper "The geometry of Finsler spaces" (available at https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-56/issue-1.P1/The-geometry-of-Finsler-spaces/bams/1183514449.full) Busemann quotes Poincaré (p. 8):

> Poincaré said
> somewhere$^5$ on the subject of generalizations: On ne fait pas un
> grand voyage pour ne trouver que ce qu'on a chez soi.

with the footnote being

> $^5$ The author forgot where he saw this remark and was unable to locate it, but
> would be grateful for a reference.

A naive search online points to Busemann's paper. I have also done naive searches on digital copies of the standard Poincaré "philosophy" books to no avail. I second Busemann.

The quote roughly translates to: "One does not make a big trip to find only what one has at home." Certainly this is in character, as far as I can see.

Thank you for your time.

---

As a disclaimer, I've asked this question on M.SE about six months ago (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4204323/169085), but the question did not get much traction.

Comment: Sounds like a quote from an old Chinese book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is a paraphrase of a passage found in the seminal paper "[Analysis Situs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_Situs_(paper))" (*Journal de l'École polytechnique*, t.1, p. 1-121, 1895; you can find it in [*Oeuvres d'Henri Poicaré*, t. VI](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/poincare.pdf), the quote is at pages 193-194, i.e. 13-14 of the scan) where he says

> Aussi y a-t-il des parties de l’Hypergéométrie auxquelles il n’y a pas lieu de beaucoup s’intéresser : telles sont, par exemple, les recherches sur la courbure des surfaces dans l’espace à n dimensions. On est sûr d’avance d’obtenir les mêmes résultats qu’en Géométrie ordinaire et **l’on n’entreprend pas un long voyage pour retrouver des spectacles tout pareils à ceux que l’on rencontre chez soi.**

i.e.

> There are also parts of the Hypergeometry in which there is no need to be very interested: for example, research on the curvature of a surface in a n-dimensional space. One is sure in advance to obtain the same results as in ordinary Geometry and one does not undertake a long journey to find spectacles quite similar to those which one meets at home.